# Need help getting my footer to do what I want it to do

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've used the sticky footer jquery solution to get my footer to always be at the bottom of the page. It works. So when I load the page with my browser in full screen mode, the footer is at the bottom and when I resize the browser, the footer does not move and cover up content which is just what I wanted. However, if the browser is already resized with a small resolution, the footer shows up and covers content. How can I stop this from happening?

[image]

The jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var docHeight = $(window).height();
    var footerHeight = $('#footer').height();
    var footerTop = $('#footer').position().top + footerHeight;

    if (footerTop < docHeight) {
        $('#footer').css('margin-top', 10 + (docHeight - footerTop) + 'px');
    }
});

// -->
```

Footer rule

```
#footer {
bottom:0;
background-color:#000000;
height: 130px;
width: 100%;
clear:both;
}
```

Comment: So what is the jQuery sticky footer you used? How are we supposed to solve this without any codes to start with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help getting this footer to do what I want it to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228166/need-help-getting-this-footer-to-do-what-i-want-it-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is the exact functionality you want but it looks like you want to be using a combination of `position:"fixed";bottom:0` and the usual `position:relative`.

Try this code and see if it behaves how you expect.
http://jsfiddle.net/Rv6p5/1/

**EDIT:** Fixed a small bug to take into account the height of the footer a little better. Also increased the size of the footer to demonstrate those changes. http://jsfiddle.net/Rv6p5/3/

Comment: just quietly, that's pretty damn elegant. I will absolutely be stealing this for my own projects, much thanks!